# mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() Generates Runtime Error in Browser

Tags: dart, web-audio-api, mediadevices

I am attempting to capture audio from an input source via a web app in a browser using the Dart 2.7.0 SDK. I want to be able to identify the available audio sources on the system so that a user could select among them (rather than relying exclusively on the default source):

```dart
captureAudio() async{
   List<MediaDeviceInfo> sources = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

    // Do more stuff here

    // Note that there are numerous differences in media APIs between those listed
    // for Dart and the JavaScript APIs shown on MDN. Those differences may or may not
    // have any effect on this error
}
```

The line of code above compiles successfully but is generating an error in Chrome 79.0.3945.88 served from Webdev in Webstorm 2019.3.1 whether in debug mode or not (note: MDN shows that the corresponding JS method call should work in Chrome):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type 'List<dynamic>' should be 'List<MediaDeviceInfo>' to implement expected type 'FutureOr<List<MediaDeviceInfo>>'.
DartError                   dart_sdk.js:5172
throw_                      dart_sdk.js:3880
castError                   dart_sdk.js:3840
cast                        dart_sdk.js:4159
check_FutureOr              dart_sdk.js:27380
(anonymous function)        dart_sdk.js:52085
Async call from Promise.then
promiseToFuture             dart_sdk.js:52087
[dartx.enumerateDevices]    dart_sdk.js:79203
captureAudio                capturewebaudio.dart:51
runBody                     dart_sdk.js:32202
_async                      dart_sdk.js:32230
captureAudio                capturewebaudio.dart:50
(anonymous function)        capturewebaudio.dart:40
_checkAndCall               dart_sdk.js:4084
dcall                       dart_sdk.js:4089
(anonymous function)        dart_sdk.js:97072
```

Dart documentation on this topic is essentially non-existent, and given the variations in Dart and JS APIs, I'm not sure what the resolution is to this problem.

Comment: This looks like it may be a bug in the API. You should post this in an issue on the [dart-lang/sdk](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues) Github page.

Comment: In dartpad the codes does not give any errors, but returns just `null`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I tried this on dartpad (great idea, BTW), and from what I could tell, the enumerateDevices() call didn't even complete properly. If sources was initialized to null, then it stayed at null. If it was initialized as an empty List object, then it stayed as an empty List object. I tried dartpad on both Chrome and Firefox. Safari does not support acquiring a mediaDevices object via the navigator (it's a deprecated method as i understand), so I wasn't able to effectively try that browser on dartpad. I think I'll submit a bug report, and see what happens with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the Dart SDK. See bug [39627](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39627) on the Dart SDK issues list. The fix is moving through the dev process.